# Is it possible to use industrial models in games?

Tags: 3d, models

Now days major of models in games only have outward appearance. E.g. autocars in action games usually have chassis, shell, tires. Some of them also have seats designed. But rarely one has engine, bearings or gears. So I'm curious about **whether industrial models can be used in games**?

Comment: Well, this site is 'game development', so I think it is welcome to ask questions about the development of the game industry.

Comment: OK, Popopo, I've edited your question to remove the parts not related to game development.

Comment: Look at Forza 4 for an example of doing just this.  Not only are the cars rendered in intricate detail (when those details are relevant), they also animate realistically (some cars have outward mechanical bits that move while driving) and under-the-hood features are detailed as well for realism and immersion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as they're saved in a format which can be read by the game engine, industrial models can be used in games like any other model. Of course, Rendering all the extra faces you won't normally see (e.g. parts on the inside) will have an impact on performance.

Also, while it certainly would be cool to have e.g. the results of a car crash calculated with realistic elastic and plastic deformations (e.g. using FEM), I don't know of any current game doing this at industrial level detail (again, due to performance issues).

Industrial simulations are often executed on specialized server clusters and still take up to multiple days, if not weeks.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but not practical. There's no reason to model the inner workings of a car in game. If you want to make the industrial specs available to the user, you can provide them in other ways.

For example, if you wanted the user to be able to print out the specs, you would provide blueprints in the appropriate format along with the game.

There's also the level of detail route available. You can use a simpler model for when the car is racing around in game, and use a highly detailed model for when the user is looking at their car in the garage.

All in all, like many things in life, there's a balancing act between two desirable features, and you need to find the balance between them that works for you. In this case you need to balance realistic models with performance.

Comment: I see, games used too detailed models will usually get lag. However, there are lots of platforms to run games: PC, XBOX, mobile phone, etc. So what I'm pondering is whether a game is designed for super computers, using industrial models, high performance physical computing, super AI and other high-end technology, so can highly simulate the real physical world. What's this? It looks like, more or less, the "Matrix"...

Comment: @Popopo Remember that we're talking about game development, not the future of technology. No one can answer what will happen in the future. I edited your question to remove the "what if?" aspect, and I'm not going to go into that in the comments either. If you're developing a game for a system that's capable of simulating an entire world at a molecular level, yes, you can use industrial models.

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, but could only imagine a performance issue. Typically, you want your models to be as simple as possible. Adding hidden features to models requires the application (game) to think more and harder.